# Ruby Convert sql into Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

do anyone know how to make the following sql into Arel?

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE enabled = true AND id IN (SELECT blog_id FROM bloggroups g join bloggroups_blogs j on g.id=j.bloggroup_id WHERE g.enabled=true AND g.label='#{params[:label]}') ORDER BY blogdate DESC"
```

Thanks

Comment: try http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not AREL.. but maybe this will help..

```
bg             = BlogGroup.where(enabled: true label: params[:label]).map(&:id)
b              = Blog.where(enabled: true).map(&:id)
returned_blogs = BlogGroupBlog.where(bloggroup_id: [bg], blog_id: [b]).blogs
```